# Javascript function shows "undefined" in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, setinterval

I have a grid of images that I want to blink on and off one at a time once through. I had the below code working a few years ago on an old site and wanted to reuse the code but I cannot get it working on the new site.

```
$('document').ready(function() {

    var myArray = ["img.square1","img.square2","img.square3","img.square4","img.square5","img.square6","img.square7","img.square8","img.square9","img.square10","img.square11","img.square12","img.square13","img.square14","img.square15"];

    console.log(myArray)
    var count = 15;
    function counter() {
        if(count < 16 && count > -1){
            $(myArray[count]).fadeTo(100, 0.1, function(){
                $(myArray[count]).fadeTo(100, 0.7, function(){
                    $(myArray[count]).fadeTo(200, 0.5, function(){
                        $(myArray[count]).fadeTo(500, 1);
                        count--
                console.log(count);
                    });                                      
                });

            });

        }else{
            clearInterval(myInterval);  
            //console.log("interval cleared");
        }
    }
    //counter();
    try{
        counter();
        alert('I guess you do exist');
    }
    catch(e){
            alert('An error has occurred: '+e.message);
    }

    console.log(counter());
    var myInterval = setInterval(counter(), 1100);
});
```

Comment: function `counter` has no return statement, this is equivalent to `return undefined`

Comment: also, note that you are doing `setInterval` incorrectly. The argument to `setInterval` needs to be a function, you are passing *the result of calling a function* - so do `var myInterval = setInterval(counter, 1100);` instead (removed `()`)

Comment: Why is `setInterval()` necessary?

Comment: After trying the below code and above suggestions I found the problem in my code it was simply the variable "count" I had changed the number of images in the array from the old/original code and did not take into account the "0" for the array so as soon as "count" was changed to 14 all good a working sample is here [link]http://marquesinteriors.com.au/check/revamp_1/[/link]

Answer (score 0):

You can substitute using `.queue()` and `.fadeTo()` callback for`setInterval()`

```
function counter(selector) {
  return $(selector).queue("images", $.map($(selector), function(image) {
    // `next` is a reference to the next function in `queueName`: `"images"`
    return function(next) { 
      return $(image).fadeTo(100, 0.1, function() {
        $(this).fadeTo(100, 0.7, function() {
          $(this).fadeTo(200, 0.5, function() {
            $(this).fadeTo(500, 1, next);
          });                                      
        });
      });
    }
  })).dequeue("images").promise("images")
}

counter("img[class^=square]")
.then(function() {
  console.log("done", this)
})
```

Comment: I could not get this code to work how I needed. I did get the original code working refer my comment above.